# The method intersects(CGRect, CGRect) is undefined for the type CGRect

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d [tutorial](http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/) but the following error occurs

> The method intersects(CGRect, CGRect) is undefined for the type CGRect

in this line

```
 if (CGRect.intersects(projectileRect, targetRect))
                targetsToDelete.add(target);
```

Is there any newer `.jar` than [this](https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/downloads/detail?name=cocos2d-android.jar&can=2&q) or something else is the problem? Because as far as I can see the `CGRect.class` does not contain the `intersects` method.

Comment: Just copy and paste that method from any running method and replace your CGRect values, It is that simple @Naskov.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to this link https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/issues/detail?id=99
and download Cocos2DSimpleGameTut1 and then copy 
**"Cocos2DSimpleGameTut1\Cocos2DSimpleGameTut1\src\org"** to your **src** folder

I test it work.